# Magento 2 add custom style

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, layout, magento2.2

I create a new Magento 2 theme extend Luma. I want to add a css file to rewrite the default Luma style.

I add in the **default_head_blocks.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/custom.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

But is not work.

For example I want to replace the search button icon with my image, but custom.css in under the style-l.css. What I can do? I can change the order of the styles?

or what is the best way to change the Luma styles?

[image]

Comment: The best way is to use less files and make changes in those files in your theme.

Comment: so if I create a new theme is not any way to rewrite the parent theme style?

Comment: you can easily re-write the style be copying the same file in your theme from parent theme.

Comment: so in my case what file I need to change to remove the search icon and to have only my image?

Comment: I have added an answer, please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to override **_icons.less** file in your theme and then make changes in that.
Example:

```
Vendor/theme/web/css/source/lib/_icons.less
```

After changing this, you need to run setup:upgrade so that files from pub get erased and then setup:static-content:deploy

alternatively, you may use grunt to compile less into CSS.